# Exporting attribute table from AGOL to CSV with domain descriptions instead of coded values

Tags: attribute-table, export, arcgis-online, domains

Does anyone know how to export an atributte table in ArcGIS Online to CSV format keeping the description of the domains instead of the codes? Is there any option or configuration where I should look at?

Answer (score 1):

For ArcMap:

[How To: Export a table to include domain descriptions and coded values](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011973)

**Geoprocessing menu > Environments > Fields drop-down > select "Transfer field domain descriptions"**

See also the answer to similar question here:

[Table attribute export to Excel with value issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/425810/table-attribute-export-to-excel-with-value-issue)

For Pro, this process is almost identical:

**Analysis ribbon > Geoprocessing group > Environments > scroll down to Fields > select "Transfer field domain descriptions"**

I tested this in Pro using CSV as my output format

More details can be found here:

[Transfer field domain descriptions (Environment setting)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/environment-settings/transfer-domain-descriptions.htm)

Cautionary tale: I found that several features had values that looked good "on paper" but apparently had been typed in or edited, as opposed to having been selected during editing from the possible values in the domain table provided in the pull-down list; for each of these features the field domain description in the export table was an empty string!  I had to go back and fix each of these in the attribute table to obtain a correct export file.