# Table attribute export to Excel with value issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, esri-geodatabase, domains

I try to export table attribute to Excel with description not code of Domain not, work with export dBASE table or table to excel not work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Table to Excel** tool as the highlighted option ticked.

[image]