# Transfer field domain descriptions during table export - keep getting empty values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-table, export, domains

I'm having trouble exporting an attribute table in ArcGIS Pro 3.1.1. Specifically, the table contains coded value domains for multiple fields, and when I export it I only get the codes -- not the code description.

I selected "Transfer field domain descriptions" in the environment settings, as described here "[Transfer field domain descriptions (Environment setting)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/environment-settings/transfer-domain-descriptions.htm)" and in this helpful post "[Exporting attribute table from AGOL to CSV with domain descriptions instead of coded values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412281/exporting-attribute-table-from-agol-to-csv-with-domain-descriptions-instead-of-c?newreg=38677525c139411f87a79b0caaffde87),"  but I ran into the issue the author mentioned at the end of that second post:

The output appended new fields that were supposed to include the domain descriptions (prefixed by d_), BUT the values for those fields were all null.

The author said "I had to go back and fix each of these in the attribute table to obtain a correct export file."

I'm not sure I understand what that means, so I'm hoping someone could expand on the solution here. My data has nearly 60,000 records and 32 fields -- 10 of which have domain codes. Going back by hand into each record wouldn't be feasible.

How can I export the descriptions without getting strings of missing values?